# Html update on Jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tabbed DIV element that changes on first click but after that loses functionality

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
<ul style="list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;">
<li><a name="CondLink"id="onlink">Link1</a></li>
<li><a name="EffLink">Link2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Javascript(Jquery):

```
$('a[name=CondLink]').click(function(){
    $('div[id=holder]').html('<ul style="list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;"><li><a name="CondLink" id="onlink">Link1</a></li><li><a name="EffLink">Link2</a></li></ul>');
});

$('a[name=EffLink]').click(function(){
    $('div[id=holder]').html('<ul style="list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;"><li><a name="CondLink">Link1</a></li><li><a name="EffLink" id="onlink">Link2</a></li></ul>');
});
```

Clicking either tab properly updates the HTML on the first click only but does does not execute either function on any followup clicks.

(NOTE: The console does not give me any errors but also does not hit a breakpoint inside either of the click functions on followup clicks)

Comment: Because at the time of binding `EffLink` - it doesn't exist. When you add the HTML you have to add the handler after, or delegate the event.

Comment: Change the selector by id for example `$("#onlink").on("click",function(){.....})`

Comment: Is it possible for the jquery to just add/remove the ID tag to the seperate list elements so i dont have to recreated and keep "EffLink" and "CondLink" bound?

Comment: yes just do `.removeAttr("id")` on the one you want to remove the id from and `attr("id", "onlink")` on the one you want to add the id to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because you're replacing your links. So the bound event listeners are no longer on the new links, so just rebind them after replacing the links.

```js
function bindClicks(){
  $('a[name=CondLink]').click(function(){
    $('div[id=holder]').html('<ul style="list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;"><li><a name="CondLink" id="onlink">Link1</a></li><li><a name="EffLink">Link2</a></li></ul>');
    bindClicks();
  });
  $('a[name=EffLink]').click(function(){
    $('div[id=holder]').html('<ul style="list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;"><li><a name="CondLink">Link1</a></li><li><a name="EffLink" id="onlink">Link2</a></li></ul>');
    bindClicks();
  });
}
bindClicks();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
<ul style="list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;">
<li><a name="CondLink"id="onlink">Link1</a></li>
<li><a name="EffLink">Link2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your further click events don't work because you override "holder's" child elements.
Basically, you delete them and add new elements which don't have a bound click event.

**Simple solution:**

Replace this:

```
$('a[name=CondLink]').click(function(){
   // code...
});
```

With this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[name=CondLink]', function(e) {
    // code...
});
```